# Storing associative data by ID

Tags: javascript

I've got a lot of (user) objects which come from a socket. On every new connection I get a new user object, but on every disconnect I just got the ID of the recently disconnected user.

What's the best way to store these user objects client-side?

Already tried something like this (pseudo code without sockets and just for testing)

```
var connectedUsers = [];

connectedUsers[12] = {
  id: 12,
  name: "Test",
  // ...
};

connectedUsers[29] = {
  id: 29,
  name: "Test 2"
};
```

Kinda works - but now I've got an array with lots of empty spaces. The upside is that it would be easy to remove a user just by his ID.

Using an object to store the objects probably won't be the right choice, since I don't have numeric indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an object. The former indices are converted to strings and taken as properties for the object.

```
var connectedUsers = {};
```

Working example:

```js
var connectedUsers = {};

connectedUsers[12] = { id: 12, name: "Test", };
connectedUsers[29] = { id: 29, name: "Test 2" };

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(connectedUsers, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks.